# Apply Trig Identity to Transform Sum of Sinusoids into Phase-Shifted Cosine Function

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, trigonometry, format

I'm trying to solve for the output of a simple RC low-pass filter, with Cos[w t] input. The convolution of the input with the RC transfer function gives me the right output, but I'd like to be able to automate getting it in the right equivalent form. Specifically, a phase-shifted Cosine function.

The convolution right now is in the form:

```
h = Cos[t w]/(1 + tau^2 w^2) + (tau w Sin[t w])/(1 + tau^2 w^2)
```

My first crack at automating the transformation is:

```
j[q_] := q /. b__ Cos[x__] + a__ Sin[x__] -> Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] Sin[x + Pi/2 + ArcTan[b/a]];

j[h]
```

But, this produces the following insane output:

```
Sqrt[tau^w^(1/(1 + tau^2 w^2)^2) + 1/(1 + tau^2 w^2)^2]
  Sin[t w + Pi/2 + ArcTan[tau^w^(1 + tau^2 w^2)/(1 + tau^2 w^2)]]
```

Any idea why the value of a isn't what I'm anticipating?

Comment: Do you get what you expect if you change `a__` to `a_` and `b__` to `b_`?

Comment: WITCHCRAFT. Also, thank you.

Comment: welcome to Mathematica.SE. I assume the change gave the desired result?

Comment: It works perfectly. Dare I ask why?

Comment: ladlibertine, examine the simpler cases: (1a) `a b c Sin[x] /. a__ Sin[_] :> a` versus (2a) `a b c Sin[x] /. a_ Sin[_] :> a`, then (1b) `a b c Sin[x] /. a__ Sin[_] :> a^2` versus (2b) `a b c Sin[x] /. a_ Sin[_] :> a^2`. Then, try `ff[a__] := a^2` and evaluate `ff[a,b,c]`. If you haven't already seen it you will find  the tutorial [Patterns Overview](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PatternsOverview.html) extremely useful.

Comment: see also [Power](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Power.html) : _" Power[x,y,z, ... ] is taken to be Power[x,Power[y,z,...]]."_

Comment: ladlibertine, I added some notes to my answer which I hope will be useful to explain the puzzle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing `a__` and `b__` to `a_` and `b_`, respectively,

```
j2[q_] := q /. b_ Cos[x__] + a_ Sin[x__] :> {{a}, {b}, {x}};
j2[h]
```

gives

> $\left( \frac{\tau  w}{\tau ^2 w^2+1}, \frac{1}{\tau ^2 w^2+1}, t w \right) $

and, the same change in OP's function `j`

```
j3[q_] :=   q /. b_ Cos[x__] + a_ Sin[x__] :>  Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] Sin[x + Pi/2 + ArcTan[b/a]];
j3[h]
```

gives

> $ \sqrt{\frac{\tau ^2 w^2}{\left(\tau ^2 w^2+1\right)^2}+\frac{1}{\left(\tau ^2 w^2+1\right)^2}} \cos \left(t w+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\tau  w}\right)\right) $

which, per OP's comment, is the desired result.

Some observations on 'why':

The combination of `BlankSequence` (`__`)  and `Power` is the source of the "insane" output the OP got. `Power` and `BlankSequence` appear together on the right-hand-side of OP's `ReplaceAll` in two separate terms: in `Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]` and, at a deeper level, in `ArcTan[b/a]`.

First, while

```
ja1[q_] := q /. b_ Cos[x__] + a_ Sin[x__] :> a
ja1[h]
```

gives the expected result (in `TeXForm`)

> $\frac{\tau  w}{\tau ^2 w^2+1}$

```
ja2[q_] := q /. b_ Cos[x__] + a__ Sin[x__] :> a
ja2[h]
```

gives

> Sequence[tau, w, 1/(1 + tau^2 w^2)]

The contribution of `Power` to the "insanity" is due to the fact that:

> Power[x,y,z, ... ]] is taken to be Power[x,Power[y,z, ... ]]. [see: Power > Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Power.html)

That is,

```
Sequence[a, b, c]^2
```

is

> $ a^{b^{c^2}} $

and

```
Sequence[tau, w, 1/(1 + tau^2 w^2)]^2
```

is

> [image]

which is what we get from

```
jb2[q_] := q /. b_ Cos[x__] + a__ Sin[x__] :> a^2
jb2[h]
```

while

```
jb1[q_] := q /. b_ Cos[x__] + a_ Sin[x__] :> a^2
jb1[h]
```

gives, as desired,

> $ \frac{\tau ^2 w^2}{\left(\tau ^2 w^2+1\right)^2} $

Note that many other functions (other than `Power`), say `Log`, would produce an error message.

Comment: This, and the exercises you outlined above, have clarified so much. Thank you, thank you, thank you for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: @ladlibertine, my pleasure. Really glad it was useful for you.

Comment: @ladlibertine,  btw just noticed that this is your first day on the site -- welcome to Mathematica.SE! Please consider visiting the [tour page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) on the basic rules of the site, and
[editing help page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for editing help.

Answer (score 3):

Pattern matching takes place on (something close to) the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of the expression rather than the display form that you see.  You can visualize it using [`TreeForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TreeForm.html):

```
h // TreeForm
```

[image]

I am not sure what you are attempting but I imagine your pattern was not written with this in mind.  What parts did you expect to match `a__`, `b__`, and `x__`?  What actually matched was:

```
h /. b__ Cos[x__] + a__ Sin[x__] :> {{a}, {b}, {x}}
```

> ```
> {{tau, w, 1/(1 + tau^2 w^2)}, {1/(1 + tau^2 w^2)}, {t w}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response (and the edit to my question)! I was hoping that `a__` would match with something like `Times[tau, w, 1/(1 + tau^2 w^2)]` (and `b__` with `1/(1 + tau^2 w^2)`, `x__` with `w t`). Looking at the `TreeForm` output, I guess my problem is that `a__` is a combination of terms from different levels? Is there a way I can better define `a__` to avoid this issue?

Comment: @ladlibertine it appears that kguler described the problem in detail so I shall assume your question is answered unless you say otherwise.